# What is the best method to get root access to Genymotion device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, root, genymotion

I'm a newbie in android development. 
I was looking for my package database in the data/data folder.I didn't find my package in the data/data folder. I found only "con" folders. (Like below image)

[image]

I was suggested by one that my device hasn't root access. He suggested to check. I checked it by using Rootchecker. Result was "the device hasn't root access".

Then I downloaded "Genymotion configuration" to root my device. And opened it and checked the option "Always allow su access (bypass Superuser app)". And clicked on "save". It required reboot. I pressed ok for rebooting. But unfortunately this process isn't going to be stopped. Like this image-

[image]

What is the solution for my problem??

Comment: what do you mean by process isn't going to be stopped?

Comment: It runs for more than 2 hour but never stops.
May be it will not stop and it will run for infinite time.

Comment: did you try creating a new device with root access?

Comment: and as the answer suggest increase width of name column and you will see the complete name

Comment: Thanks bro for helping me. Such a normal case, but I did just like an idiot. Many many thanks to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually that folder are not `con` folder.
just increase name box and u will get full name of all folders listed in data/data folder.

Comment: wait i ll post image

Comment: Thank u so much bro. Actually I did a job like idiot. Thanks for solution. such a easy solution.

Comment: [See this image][1]


  [1]: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nLyuvgQBWD4/VsQJDJNfdHI/AAAAAAAAIUQ/tlj3ihwTVik/s1600/x5OUk.png

Comment: Thanks.
Do you wanna vote my question to grow up my reputation?

Comment: Thanks to u again bro :)